# Why was this question (about browser-based remote desktop software) closed as "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

One of my questions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466780/embedding-a-desktop-application-window-in-a-web-page, was closed as "not constructive", with no specific explanation being given as to why it was closed. This left me wondering what the rationale was for the question's closing, since no one pointed out any specific problems with this question.

Specifically, I was trying figure out how to display a local desktop application (running on the same computer) in a local web page, inside an iframe. I'm not sure what was wrong with this question, specifically - was it too broad, too vague, too subjective, or too argumentative, or was it closed for some other reason?

Comment: Because of this question's relative obscurity, I don't know whether it will ever be re-opened, even if I edit it to make it less vague.

Comment: Addressing your comment, and not your question: there are three things, I think, you can do you focus attention back on your question: edit it (which bumps it to the top of the home page), flag it for moderator attention, or post a question here, like you have.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I'm usually hesitant to post questions here, since questions on Meta Stack Overflow tend to get more downvotes than questions on other Q&A sites - is there any way to get feedback on these issues without risking damage to reputation?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Also, I wouldn't expect a response from moderators if I simply asked them to re-open my question Is there any other way to re-open a question that was subsequently edited?

Comment: This is the right thing to do, posting here. True, this'll sometimes attract downvotes to your question, but it'll sometimes attract upvotes too. And reopen votes, crucially.

Comment: One thing I'm missing, as I read your question, is context. *Why* do you want to do this? What led you to this (unusual) idea? That would help.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I'm basically trying to simulate a desktop environment inside the web browser by allowing desktop application windows to be dragged around inside a browser window.

Comment: Yeah, I got that bit. Why?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta It would make it easier for web developers to create "window managers" using HTML5 and Javascript - that's the main reason. It would also make it possible to re-arrange (and perhaps resize) windows using familiar JavaScript libraries such as JQuery.

Comment: I'd expand on that, and add that to your question. Also useful - what constraints you're operating under: what browsers and apps you must support, for example.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I'd definitely try to support as many browsers and operating systems as possible. Also, I recently found a software package called Guacamole that might be suitable for this purpose.

Comment: +1 because you said *specifically* to downvote your question.

Comment: Please refrain from vandalizing your own question and/or using Meta's general desire to do the opposite thing from what you've requested to effectively beg for upvotes.  :p

Comment: @Charles Sorry for my ill-advised post - I was only asking for downvotes because I felt guilty about posting the question that's being discussed here. I have reverted the changes - no need to worry.

Comment: reference reading: **[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically your question lacks the kind of detail that makes up a good question; phrases such as "using some kind of remote desktop protocol" and "as many platforms as possible" are vague and open for free interpretation. Don't throw unknown unknowns at people.

Also, writers of good questions put in some kind of effort to solve the problem themselves and  will highlight what didn't work, so that the community has a specific problem to work with. If you had asked me, I would have closed it as NARQ.

Lastly, the way you've tagged your question is not attracting the right crowd, [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) is used in the web development realm, but what you're asking for is not something any web developer would have to deal with.

Comment: Would "cross-platform" be any less vague than "as many platforms as possible", or would that term need to be clarified as well (since it's synonymous with the previous one?)

Comment: Also, at this point, I can't really specify which type of remote desktop protocol to use, because I don't yet know which one would be the best for this purpose. (Basically, I know what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how I should do it. I'm trying to find out what my options would be, so some of the vaguess of the question is difficult to resolve.)

Comment: @AndersonGreen I would advice you to turn your unknown unknowns into something better first.

Comment: Is "all platforms" any less vague than "as many platforms as possible", or is that still considered too vague?

Answer (score 1):

The general audience ("We") can not tell you what is suitable for what you (vaguely) plan to do sometime in the future.

With so much fragility, question normally turn out to become not constructive. There is no common set (yet) that allows to communicate your thoughts and question to others. Which would have been a pre-condition to answer it.

From the product your raised:

Whether or not Guacamole suits your needs, I can not say.

You might also be interested in [Broadway (demo video)](http://people.gnome.org/~alexl/broadway-screencast-3.webm).

Comment: If Stack Overflow isn't the right place for such subjective questions, then is there a better place where they can be discussed? (I know that software recommendation questions are considered off-topic here - there must be a better forum for these questions.)

Comment: Well you can seek out for developers across the globe that are active in the field and develop your own, too. You will then normally find peer-groups in which you can discuss all the issues with all bells and whistles.

Comment: What is the software (Broadway) called, specifically? I'm still trying to find its website.

Comment: OK, here's more relevant links related to Broadway: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=broadway+gtk&oq=broadway+gtk&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i10i30j0i30l2.14722.17582.4.17798.13.13.0.0.0.0.127.1164.11j2.13.0.les%3Beqn%2Ccconf%3D1-2%2Cmin_length%3D2%2Crate_low%3D0-035%2Crate_high%3D0-035%2Csecond_pass%3Dfalse%2Cnum_suggestions%3D2%2Cignore_bad_origquery%3Dtrue%2Conetoken%3Dfalse..0.0...1c.1.a6roeORZkGE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ&fp=df08fc36998c1ff1&bpcl=40096503&biw=1366&bih=631